# Retrieve data from many to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I know the question has been responded many times, but for some reason I couldn't make it work for my tables, no matter what, and I don't understand why.

I've been trying this for like 4 hours and I couldn't get it done right.

So here are my functions from two models:

ConducatorDoctorat

```
public function materii()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\DomeniuDoctorat', 'profesor_domeniu', 'domeniu_id', 'profesor_id');
    }
```

DomeniuDoctorat

```
public function materii()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\ConducatorDoctorat', 'profesor_domeniu', 'profesor_id', 'domeniu_id');
    }
```

and profesor_domeniu schema:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ProfesorDomeniu extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profesor_domeniu', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('profesor_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('domeniu_id');
            
            $table->foreign('profesor_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('conducatori_doctorat')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('domeniu_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('domenii_doctorat')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profesor_domeniu');
    }
}
```

In my controller, I tried so many ways to do it, for example, like this:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $materii = ConducatorDoctorat::findOrFail($id)->materii()->pluck('domeniu_id');

        return view('admin.conducatori_doctorat.edit')->with([
            'materii' => $materii
        ]);
    }
```

but it still doesn't work.

With the given $id, I want to retrieve all the data from profesor_domeniu where profesor_id == $id.
That's all, but I can't get it.

How can this be done and why doesn't my approach work?

//edit for clarity:

conducator_doctorat is where the professors are stored and domenii_doctorat is where their fields are stored.

In profesor_domeniu, I store what each professor teaches, by linking an id from conducatori_doctorat to an id of a field from domenii_doctorat.

//edit2:

materii() means the fields they teach.

//edit3:

My many-to-many relationship with some data added into the pivot table profesor_domeniu.

[image: click]

Comment: where is your professor relationship ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul what do you mean?

Comment: `ConducatorDoctorat` means ? your table name is confusion

Comment: @KamleshPaul I edited my initial post for clarity. Sorry :)

Comment: so one `professor` can have many `fields` ? and you want to get `professors data` with there respected `fields` ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul one professor can have multiple fields, and those fields can be associated with many professors. I want to get only the fields associated with each professor.

Comment: then if your relationship is correct you can do this `FieldsModel::with('professors')->get()`  or `ProfessorModel::with('fields')->get()`

Comment: @KamleshPaul if I do any of that, I will get an array with all the fields available or with all the professors available (from domenii_doctorat or from conducatori_doctorat). I need to get the data from the pivot table, profesor_domeniu, where profesor_id == $id from the edit route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eager load your relationship on your model :

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $conducatorDoctorat = ConducatorDoctorat::with('materii')->findOrFail($id);

       $materii = $conducatorDoctorat->materii;

        return view('admin.conducatori_doctorat.edit')->with([
            'materii' => $materii
        ]);
    }
```

you can also request only your materii related to your conducatorDoctorat :

```
public function edit($id)
    {
       

       $materii = DomeniuDoctorat::whereHas('materii', function($query) use ($id){
             $query->where('id', $id);
       })->get();

        return view('admin.conducatori_doctorat.edit')->with([
            'materii' => $materii
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Can you update you question with a basic example of what your 3 tables look likes ?

Comment: You were right. I'm sorry. I was doing something else wrong.